# How to invoke default constructor of Type T if passed argument is nullptr?

Tags: c++

I have a function which takes `std::string` type as argument, but I'd like to pass a null pointer to it and construct an empty string. Right now, I'm using if else statements to accomplish this task, but I'd like to pretty much find modern elegant solutions for this problem.

```
void print(int age, std::string name, int familyMembers, std::string state) {
   std::cout << name << age << familyMembers << state << "\n";
}

print(10, "sara", 5, nullptr);
print(10, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr); // Doesn't work
print(nullptr, nullptr, 12, nullptr); // Doesn't work
```

I need a runtime solution. The following works,

```
std::string fromJS(const char * cstr) { return cstr ? { cstr };
```

but,

```
print(10, fromJS(nullptr), 5, fromJS(nullptr));
```

can become horrible as arguments increase..

I'm looking for a solution that do this automatically at print function level

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232570/discussion-on-question-by-jeffbrtc-how-to-invoke-default-constructor-of-type-t-i).

Answer (score 2):

Just make an override for [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t).

```cpp
void print(std::string name) {
   std::cout << name << "\n";
}

void print(std::nullptr_t) {
   std::cout << "\n";
}

print(nullptr);
```

**Update**: For such a "print" function with indeterminate parameters, you should use template expansion instead:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void print(const T& arg, const Ts&... args) {
    std::cout << arg;
    print(args);
}

template <typename... Ts>
void print(std::nullptr_t, const Ts&... args) {
    print(args);
}

template <typename T>
void print(const T& name) {
   std::cout << name << "\n";
}

void print(std::nullptr_t) {
   std::cout << "\n";
}

print(1, 1.0, "hello", nullptr, "hello"s, nullptr);
```

Comment: this doesn't looks elegant in my real world app because the places of parameters are unordered and it will cause me to write 10-20 overload functions

Comment: @jeffbRTC What do you mean by "*the places of parameters are unordered*"?

Comment: Check my edit on question!!!

Comment: @jeffbRTC See update

Comment: Does your templated solution works at Runtime?

Comment: @jeffbRTC Why work at runtime?

Comment: because my C++ function get called at Runtime by C not at compile time.

Comment: @jeffbRTC In your code where you've written `nullptr` as an argument to `print`, what does the actual C code do? Pass `NULL`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The C code can pass C style null pointer to there.

Comment: @jeffbRTC Oh, ok, that probably explains some of the confusion. The `std::nullptr_t` overloads won't be useful in that case. You actually need to check if you get a null pointer in your function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I actually check that ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) and it's `value_or` and `nullopt` instead of `nullptr`, so your code became

```
void print(std::optional<std::string> name) {
   std::cout << name.value_or("empty string passed") << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   print("non empty"); // prints non empty
   print(nullopt);     // prints empty string passed
   //NOTE: in last line I used nullopt instead of nullptr
}
```

Comment: I can't use this because it involve same if else statements.

Comment: See my comments on question... Can't repeat everything again!!

Comment: @jeffbRTC where in this answer is `if else`?

Comment: then just write your own ```std::optional``` that can be constructed with nullptr

Comment: @Caleth Because I have to check if passed value is nullptr to pass nullopt which involves same if else statements

Comment: @jeffbRTC you don't have `nullptr`s! the value `0` is not the same as the value `nullptr`

Comment: @Caleth It's nullptr when I pass from Javascript.

Comment: @jeffbRTC `nullptr` and "a null pointer" are different things. I really doubt that your JS is mapping `0` to `nullptr`

Comment: @Caleth It really does.. https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/WebIDL-Binder.html

Comment: Nowhere on that page is a single mention of ```nullptr```
https://emscripten.org/search.html?q=nullptr&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: @jeffbRTC you can just override some function so if it gets ```nullptr```, it'll return ```nullopt``` otherwise it just return what was passed(basic [example](https://godbolt.org/z/757fWvscs))(or you can do the same with [auto instead of template](https://godbolt.org/z/qzK6xMqEh)), but this will looks like @iBug answer

Comment: @jeffbRTC I don't think that WebIDL Binder could work with templates. It would need to have instantiated all the required (at runtime) template instances. Anyway, the information about calling that C++ function from some JS binding mechanism is quite crucial. It should be present in the question itself. Possibly even with some example of how it is invoked from JS code.

Comment: @DanielLangr No, I don't use WebIDL binder at all. Just want to point out that what happen when you pass 0 from JS to C function that takes const char*.  Yes, It happen at Runtime of course.